# Why the directory name was parsed wrong?

Tags: symbolic-link

I want to link /var/www/html/wp  to /windows/wamp/www/wp.

```
ln -s  /var/www/html/wp   /windows/wamp/www/wp
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/windows/wamp/www/wp/wp’: Operation not permitted
```

Why /windows/wamp/www/wp  was pared into  /windows/wamp/www/wp/wp?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is already a **directory**

```
/windows/wamp/www/wp
```

In that case "ln -s" takes the name part from the target "/var/www/html/wp" (what is "wp") and tries to create a symbolic link in the directory "/windows/wamp/www/wp" with the name "wp" (what ends up in "/windows/wamp/www/wp/wp") targeting "/var/www/html/wp".

Furthermore it seems that you do not have sufficent rights to create a file in the directory "/windows/wamp/www/wp/".